# Move a set to another scene even though it’s done

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, scene

I have finished my video, but I put everything in one scene. There are a total of four sets. Is it possible to move a set to another scene  and render that other scene by itself or is it to late?

Comment: A "set", like a movie set? meaning floor walls and architectural items? or a group of actions and poses?  what kind of "set" do yo mean?

Comment: a movie set with copies of the characters

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new scene.

[image]
<sub>(source: [blender.org](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/_images/data-system_scenes_introduction_menu.png))</sub>

You can then choose to link or copy your assets

[image]

(For 2.8)

[image]

(blatant quote from the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/scenes/introduction.html?highlight=full%20copy))

> **New**
>
> Creates an empty scene with default values.
>
> **Copy Settings**
>
> Creates an empty scene, but also copies the settings from the active scene into the new one.
>
> **Link Objects**
>
> This option creates a new scene with the same settings and contents as the active scene. However, instead of copying the objects, the new scene contains links to the objects in the old scene. Therefore, changes to objects in the new scene will result in the same changes to the original scene, because the objects used are literally the same. The reverse is also true.
>
> **Link Object Data**
>
> Creates new, duplicate copies of all of the objects in the currently selected scene, but each one of those duplicate objects will have links to the object-data (meshes, materials and so on) of the corresponding objects in the original scene.
>
> This means that you can change the position, orientation and size of the objects in the new scene without affecting other scenes, but any modifications to the object-data (meshes, materials, etc.) will also affect other scenes. This is because a single instance of the “object-data” is now being shared by all of the objects in all of the scenes, that link to it. This has the effect of making a new independent copy of the object-data.
>
> **Full Copy**
>
> Using this option, nothing is shared. This option creates a fully independent scene with copies of the active scene’s contents. Every object in the original scene is duplicated, and a duplicate, private copy of its object-data is made as well.