# Easiest way to create scene variant and manage objects?

Tags: objects, groups, outliner

I've designed a kitchen set with many objects and I would like to create another variant of it where about 95% of the objects will stay intact and only few will be moved/added. I also want to keep the old variant and be able to quickly switch between the two and compare them. What is the best way to do this?

I've already made couple of variants for the bathroom by just simply creating an empty for each new variant, and copy-paste objects form other variants. Now I'm just toggling visibility of the variants for comparison. This method works but I'm not happy with it.

- Copying object's multiplies geometry in the file
- Copying process itself is not convenient. When I want to copy some object from previous variant I must unhide previous variant, find and select the object in outliner if it's already obscured in the scene. Then I Ctrl-c, Ctrl-v. Move the object to be sure that it's copied. Unselect original object. Hide previous variant. Find new copy of the object in the outliner because for some reason it's not copied to selected parent. Hold mouse button on the object while scrolling again through long list in outliner to drop it on new variant. Move the object to original place in previous variant. Is there any plugin maybe that will give an context menu option in outliner to copy/paste?
- I sometimes forgot to hold Ctrl while clicking on visibility button or trying to select an object and weird things happens. Clicking in outliner without Ctrl is only usable if I want to move an empty.
- Switching to the variant that I'm looking for requires many clicks and is not super easy if I have a few. I want to quickly switch to some other variant, so I unhide it in outliner and realize that some other variant is also unhidden, so I'm hidding it (the scene looks the same because objects are exactly overlapped). Then I play a bit, select an object, hit Delete key and upss... the object is still there and I deleted it in wrong variant...
- Objects need unique names in entire tree and I'm not event aware that some other object's name changes when I give the same name to new object.

I'm trying to be organized but it seems like Blender never aimed for easy objects management. I also see this when watching some others work. Most of the time the file is just Cube-Cube.077 right in the scene or event worse, all objects joined into one big static mesh...

I'm already aware of and tried objects grouping, and linking but those methods seem to complicate things even more than my actual approach, without any benefits that will be worth it. Is there any better way to do similar tasks in blender?

Comment: Does this have something to do with animation-nodes?

Comment: I'm sorry NO, I've had this tags from previous question, I've chosen new one but there was some error when I tried to post so I had to reload the page and old tags are back...

Comment: Multiple bullet point (especially the last) sound like a rant. Using questions with question marks helps attract useful answers. Also, there seem to be multiple question included in this post. Please only post one question per post, you can post as many separate questions as necessary, but try make them applicable to not only your case, by wording them in a general fashion.

Comment: (1) Copying only the object, not the datablock, will not increase the file size (Alt D).

Comment: (2) If you want to duplicate an object, use Shift D / Alt D, it will remain in the original hierarchy.

Comment: I was trying to describe precisely what I'm trying to do and how I do that right now so people will not propose the same thing that I've already tried.  Additional question is only for helping to understand what kind of hacks I'm looking for to feel more productive. I can't ask questions for every single functionality that I think would be nice but I don't know if it exist and also there may be some nice functionalities that I did't even wished/Imagined, so how I ask questions about them? Context menu is example The task is very specific, and I think not only me wonder how to manage the scene

Comment: You can use scenes. You can then choose to copy the objects or to link data. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105746/move-a-set-to-another-scene-even-though-it-s-done/105762#105762